# Dependencias incumplidas con python-sphinx

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Utilice el comando `sudo purge python` sin saber que estaba borrando archivos importantes para el ubuntu porque tenia unos problemas con las librerías de python y quería volver a instalarlas todas desde el principio.
El problema es que cuando intente instalar de nuevo las librerías me salto un error. Entonces intente arreglar mi error de borrar todo python con `sudo apt-get install python` pero me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
>      python-sphinx : Depende: sphinx-common (= 1.3.6-2ubuntu1) pero 1.3.6-2ubuntu1.1 va a ser instalado
>      python3-sphinx : Depende: sphinx-common (= 1.3.6-2ubuntu1) pero 1.3.6-2ubuntu1.1 va a ser instalado
> ```

Entonces cuando intento instalar las dependencias que faltan con `sudo apt-get install python-sphinx` o `sudo apt-get install python3-sphinx` me aparecen los siguientes errores respectivamente en la terminal:

> ```
> Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
>      python3-sphinx : Depende: sphinx-common (= 1.3.6-2ubuntu1) pero 1.3.6-2ubuntu1.1 va a ser instalado`
>
> Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
>     python-sphinx : Depende: sphinx-common (= 1.3.6-2ubuntu1) pero 1.3.6-2ubuntu1.1 va a ser instalado
> ```

¿Cómo puedo conseguir estos paquetes si dependen el uno del otro? ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema si no es usando `apt-get`?

Comment: Lo raro es que el sistema siga en pie, Python no es solo un intérprete, es medio Ubuntu. Prueba actualizando sphinx-common primero: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install sphinx-common`. Seguramente te surgan más problemas. Se me ocurre que podrias intentar ir a `/var/log/apt/history.log` y buscar lo que eliminaste (`Purge:`) para ver lo que y reinstalarlo. Otra opción podría ser instalar el escritorio al completo `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @FJSevilla Todas las opciones sugeridas me han dado los mismos errores en las dependencias que muestro en el comentario original. ¿La única solución que me queda es volver a instalarme Ubuntu, verdad?

Comment: Nunca hay nada perdido, se recuperan sistemas con el kernel borrado... Prueba a purgar ese paquete antes `sudo apt-get purgue sphinx-common`. Es difícil ayudar a distancia. Si no deseas más dolores de cabeza, considerando la magnitud del problema, si tienes tu /home en una partición  independiente creo que lo más simple es reinstalar. En caso contrario haz una copia de seguridad de tus archivos antes de ello. Saludos.